# Nginx rewrites static files to index.html

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to work on a single page app - I need to rewrite all urls to index.html but allow existing static files (.css and .js) to be served as they normally would be in a browser.

This is the code that I'm trying to use to re-write but it serves my static files to the re-write as well

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't actually need a rewrite for that in nginx, just use try_files like so:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

what this does is for all url's:

1. try the exact static filename match, and serve it if present
2. if 1 didn't serve anything, then server /index.html instead

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
server {
    listen          1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name     domain.eu;
    root            /usr/local/www/domain.eu/public;

    try_files       $uri @rewrites;

    location @rewrites {
        rewrite   ^/favicon.ico$   /pictures/favicon.ico   last;
        rewrite   ^                /index.html             last;
    }
}
```